# Escaping wildcard for grep in bash scripts

Tags: bash, grep

How does one do globs for grep?  Should one escape the wildcard (`*`) inside bash scripts?  Or only escape it when writing on the command line?  How can I detect the enclosing brackets pattern `{...}` in a variable?

```
#!/bin/bash
phrs="Gnu"
fdir=( "$HOME" )
isufx=( "--include=\*.{c,cpp,f95,f90,f03,f08}" )
grep --null -r -l "${isufx[@]}" -e "$phrs" -- "${fdir[@]}"
```

Comment: Please try to avoid *chameleon questions* - your original question didn't mention arrays at all (so I had to modify my answer substantially)

Comment: From your answer I realised I needed to put more information.

Comment: Should I put a new question?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO best practice would be to escape (or quote) it **unless** you have disabled globbing altogether with `set -f` or `set -o noglob`. If nothing else, that makes your intent clear:

```
isufx=( --include=\*.{c,cpp,f95,f90,f03,f08} )
```

*If you use quotes, then remember that brace expansion is being done by the shell regardless, so must be unquoted.* In particular, to allow brace expansion inside the array constructor:

```
isufx=( "--include=*."{c,cpp,f95,f90,f03,f08} )
```

However, globs match against the whole *word*, so you'd need to have a filename like `--include=foo.c` or `--include=bar.f95` in order for the `*` to actually get expanded by the shell.

Comment: This is how I am using grep:  `grep -rl --include=\*.{org,texi,tex} -e "$phrs" -- "$dir"`

Comment: I do not think I need to input a filename for the `--include` option.