# Detecting an opening { and a closing } in a variable

Tags: bash

How can I detect an opening `{` and a closing `}` in variables such as

```
 var="\*.{cp,cpp,f90,f95,f03,f08}"
```

The following did not work

```
[[ "$ext" =~ {(.*)} ]] && echo "Detected {}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple *pattern matching* with `==` (or, equivalently, `=`) inside a bash `[[ ... ]]` extended test construct:

```
[[ $var == *{*}* ]]
```

Word  splitting  and pathname expansion are not performed inside `[[ ... ]]` so you don't need to quote either the LHS or RHS.

If you want to use *regular expression* matching, then you will need to escape or quote the braces  because they are special in a bash extended regex, but **not** the `.*`:

```
[[ $var =~ \{.*\} ]]
```

or

```
[[ $var =~ "{".*"}" ]]
```

Note the following additional differences:

- ordinary *pattern matching* (with `==`) works on the whole string, so you need at least a leading `*` wildcard to match what comes before the opening brace (and a trailing `*` if you expect characters after the closing brace)
- *regular expression matching* (`=~`) matches anywhere in the string (unless anchored with `^` and/or `$`) so you can get away with just the wildcard match `.*` in between. Strictly speaking it should be `\{[^}]*\}` to match a sequence of non-closing braces followed by a closing brace.

---

*All that having been said, I suspect that you really don't want to place* `\*.{cp,cpp,f90,f95,f03,f08}` *in a **variable**, because the brace expansion won't actually expand unless you resort to hacks like* `eval echo "$var"`.

Comment: I only want it to expand when calling the command `grep -rl -e "$phrs" -- $var`

Comment: @Backy I don't think that will work - as I suggested in [your previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411397/escaping-wildcard-for-grep-in-bash-scripts), you can use an array `arr=( --include=\*.{c,cpp,f95,f90,f03,f08} )` where the **un**quoted brace gets expanded by your shell, then `grep -rl "${arr[@]}" -e "$phrs" .`

Comment: I would then set the include command directly in  `isufx`, rather than storing in a variable .

Comment: @Backy yes if you prefer, `grep -rl --include=\*.{cp,cpp,f90,f95,f03,f08} -e "$phrs" .`

Comment: Which then expands to `--include=*.cp --include=*.cpp  ...`

Comment: @Backy yes it does

Answer (score 0):

Try this in bash to see the results:

```
var="\*.{cp,cpp,f90,f95,f03,f08}"
[[ $var =~ "{" ]] && echo found || echo not in var
[[ $var =~ "X" ]] && echo found || echo not in var
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).